# The name does not exist in the current context (in ActionResult with MVC Entity Framework)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

In ActionResult "Details(int? id)" of a controller I have (in ActionResult this is inside of an condition: if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) { bla, bla):

```
            var TheUser = db.AspNetUsers.Where(u => u.Id == CurrentUser)
                         .Select(u => new
                         {
                             ID = u.Id,
                             Email = u.Email,
                             Username = u.UserName,
                             Surrname = u.Surname,
                             Name = u.Name,
                             Role = u.Role,
                             CreditBalance = u.CreditBalance
                         }).Single();

            var TheJournal = db.CreditJournal.Where(tj => tj.CvID == id && tj.UseBy == CurrentUser)
                            .Select(tj => new
                               {
                                   IdJournal = tj.IdJournal,
                                   Operation = tj.Operation,
                                   CvID = tj.CvID,
                                   CreditConsumed = tj.CreditConsumed,
                                   UseDate = tj.UseDate,
                                   UseBy = tj.UseBy
                               });

            var Counter = TheJournal.Count();
```

When I evaluate values in Debug Mode I have:

```
TheUser |>>>    { ID = "56cc2430-4db5-4799-ad41-fa1d103d1967", Email = "sales@maps4u.ro", Username = "sales@maps4u.ro", Surrname = "Laurentiu", Name = "LAZAR", Role = 3, CreditBalance = 75 }  <Anonymous Type>

TheJournal |>>> {System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<<>f__AnonymousType9<int,string,int?,int?,System.DateTime?,string>>}  System.Linq.IQueryable<<>f__AnonymousType9<int,string,int?,int?,System.DateTime?,string>> {System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<<>f__AnonymousType9<int,string,int?,int?,System.DateTime?,string>>}

Counter |>>>    The name 'Counter' does not exist in the current context
```

What can be wrong in the simple code shown above? (The equivalent SQL statement for TheJornal returns for the given criteria, at least 4 records).
Somehow I think to declare the variables outside the condition, but what type do they have to be? (Anyway the first, TheUser is just ok, the issue starts with second, TheJournal )

Comment: use `.ToList()` for your `TheJournal` query. And then for `var Counter = TheJournal.Count`. Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: @ramiramilu thank you, now is ok. I did not take count that here (almost every time) it returns a list of values, and not a single record such as TheUser.

Comment: Glad I am helpful for you. Posted the same comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.ToList()` for your `TheJournal` query. And then use Count to get the Counter -

`var Counter = TheJournal.Count`